# Projectiles aren't getting drawn

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I'm at the first semester of computer science and my exam is to make a game.

I've decided to make a shooter game in which the character is centralized and shoots other things, much like asteroids. I've managed to make the aim system, that is controlled by my mouse, work, but I can't seem to find a way to shoot properly.

My first try was to do the basics, create a projectile and make it move with my click, but I could still control it in the air and it didn't return to the gun. After that, I roamed the internet till I came up the this final code and, when it didn't work, I couldn't find anything else to do.
The problematic part of this code is: the projectiles get in and out of the list (bullets), but they don't get drawn.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
var ctt = canvas.getContext('2d')
var w = canvas.width
var h = canvas.height
console.log(w, h)
//canvas is 800x450

// characters
var hero = {
    x: 400,
    y: 225,
    ray: 35,
    start: 0,
    end: 2 * Math.PI,
    angle: 0,
    corf: 'n',
    cord: 'red',
    draw: function (){
        ctt.beginPath()
        ctt.arc(this.x, this.y, this.ray, this.start, this.end)
        if (this.corf != 'n'){
            ctt.strokeStyle = this.corf
            ctt.stroke()
        }
        if (this.cd != 'n'){
            ctt.fillStyle = this.cord
            ctt.fill()
        }
        }
}
var gun = {
    xs: 400,
    ys: 225,
    xe: 450,
    ye: 225,
    cor: 'yellow',
    width: 15,
    draw: function(){
        ctt.beginPath()
        ctt.moveTo(this.xs, this.ys)
        ctt.lineTo(this.xe, this.ye)
        ctt.strokeStyle = this.cor
        ctt.lineWidth = this.width
        ctt.stroke()
        }
    }

var enemy = {}
var bullets = []
//funções
function createProjectile(x, y, angle){
    var projectile = {
        x: x,
        y: y,
        ray: 7.5,
        start: 0,
        end: 2 * Math.PI,
        angle: angle,
        velocity: 10,
        corf: 'n',
        cord: 'gray',
        draw: function (){
            ctt.beginPath()
            ctt.arc(this.x, this.y, this.ray, this.start, this.end)
            if (this.corf != 'n'){
                ctt.strokeStyle = this.corf
                ctt.stroke()
            }
            if (this.cd != 'n'){
                ctt.fillStyle = this.cord
                ctt.fill()
            }
            }
    }
    return projectile
}

function aim(){
    ctt.clearRect(0, 0, w, h)
    const dx = mousex - 400
    const dy = mousey - 225
    const d = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
    var sen = dy / d
    var cos = dx / d
    gun.xe = cos * 55 + w/2
    gun.ye = sen * 55 + h/2
    var needle = createProjectile(gun.xe, gun.ye, gun.angle)
    needle.draw()
    gun.draw()
}

function update(){
    for(var i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++){
        bullets[i].x += Math.cos(bullets[i].angle) * bullets[i].v
        bullets[i].y += Math.sin(bullets[i].angle) * bullets[i].v
    }
    bullets = bullets.filter(function(bul){
        return (bul.x > 0 && bul.x < 800 && bul.y > 0 && bul.y < 450)
    })
    for(var i = 0; i <bullets.length; i++){
        bullets[i].draw()
    }
    aim()
    hero.draw()
    requestAnimationFrame(update)
}

//code
document.addEventListener('click', function(eve){
    var b = createProjectile(400, 225, hero.angle)
    bullets.push(b)
})
let mousex, mousey
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(eve){
    let r = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
    mousex = eve.clientX - r.left
    mousey = eve.clientY - r.top
    var angle = Math.atan2(mousey - 225, mousex - 400)
    hero.angle = angle
})

update()
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    background-image: url('background.jpeg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
#header{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background-color: powderblue;
}
a{
    padding: 50px;
    color: midnightblue;
    text-decoration: none;
    
    font-weight:700;
    font-size: 25px;
}

#corpo{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
#eu{
    color:powderblue;
    background-color: midnightblue;
    width: 70%;
    height: 400px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
#credito{
    font-size: 25px;
    justify-self: flex-start;
    align-self: flex-start;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
table{
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}
th{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#canvas{
    background-color: lightseagreen;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ursal</title>
    <link href = style.css rel = stylesheet>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = header>
        <a href="home.html">Home</a>
        <a href = 'jogo.html'>Jogo</a>
        <a href = 'creditos.html'>Créditos</a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <canvas id = canvas width = 800 height = 450 ></canvas>
        <script src = 'script.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Protip: Don't use or mention chatbots. They're not helpful in 2023 and are just a distraction.

Comment: Protip: Use double quotes on all your HTML attributes. It makes it more readable and distinguishes it when mixed with JavaScript (which should have single quotes), eliminating the need for escaping.

Comment: Protip: Single-character variable names won't make you any friends. Use intuitive names for coders and a minifier for the browser.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the first loop of your `update` function you use `bullets[i].v` property, which isn't created in `createProjectile`. I guess you meant it to be `bullets[i].velocity`.
2. You need to rework the way you clear the canvas. If you fix the point above, then comment out the part where you clear the canvas (`ctt.clearRect(0, 0, w, h)`), the bullet will be drawn and leave a trace behind. E.g. you can clear the canvas before you draw the bullets.

Here is the JS code with several fixes:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
var ctt = canvas.getContext('2d')
var w = canvas.width
var h = canvas.height
console.log(w, h)
//canvas is 800x450

// characters
var hero = {
    x: 400,
    y: 225,
    ray: 35,
    start: 0,
    end: 2 * Math.PI,
    angle: 0,
    corf: 'n',
    cord: 'red',
    draw: function () {
        ctt.beginPath()
        ctt.arc(this.x, this.y, this.ray, this.start, this.end)
        if (this.corf != 'n') {
            ctt.strokeStyle = this.corf
            ctt.stroke()
        }
        if (this.cd != 'n') { // This doesn't do anything
            ctt.fillStyle = this.cord
            ctt.fill()
        }
    }
}
var gun = {
    xs: 400,
    ys: 225,
    xe: 450,
    ye: 225,
    cor: 'yellow',
    width: 15,
    draw: function () {
        ctt.beginPath()
        ctt.moveTo(this.xs, this.ys)
        ctt.lineTo(this.xe, this.ye)
        ctt.strokeStyle = this.cor
        ctt.lineWidth = this.width
        ctt.stroke()
    }
}

var enemy = {}
var bullets = []
//funções
function createProjectile(x, y, angle) {
    var projectile = {
        x: x,
        y: y,
        ray: 7.5,
        start: 0,
        end: 2 * Math.PI,
        angle: angle,
        velocity: 10,
        corf: 'n',
        cord: 'gray',
        draw: function () {
            ctt.beginPath()
            ctt.arc(this.x, this.y, this.ray, this.start, this.end)
            if (this.corf != 'n') {
                ctt.strokeStyle = this.corf
                ctt.stroke()
            }
            if (this.cd != 'n') { // This doesn't do anything
                ctt.fillStyle = this.cord
                ctt.fill()
            }
        }
    }
    return projectile
}

function aim() {
    const dx = mousex - 400
    const dy = mousey - 225
    const d = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
    var sen = dy / d
    var cos = dx / d
    gun.xe = cos * 55 + w / 2
    gun.ye = sen * 55 + h / 2
    var needle = createProjectile(gun.xe, gun.ye, gun.angle)
    needle.draw()
    gun.draw()
}

function update() {
    ctt.clearRect(0, 0, w, h) // Moved this here

    for (var i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++) {
        bullets[i].x += Math.cos(bullets[i].angle) * bullets[i].velocity // Fixed these
        bullets[i].y += Math.sin(bullets[i].angle) * bullets[i].velocity // Fixed these
    }
    bullets = bullets.filter(function (bul) {
        return (bul.x > 0 && bul.x < 800 && bul.y > 0 && bul.y < 450)
    })
    for (var i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++) {
        bullets[i].draw()
    }
    aim()
    hero.draw()
    requestAnimationFrame(update)
}

//code
// fire bullet on mousedown instead of click (which is mouseup)
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function (eve) {
    var b = createProjectile(gun.xe, gun.ye, hero.angle) // generate bullet from gun instead of hero
    bullets.push(b)
})
let mousex, mousey
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (eve) {
    let r = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
    mousex = eve.clientX - r.left
    mousey = eve.clientY - r.top
    var angle = Math.atan2(mousey - 225, mousex - 400)
    hero.angle = angle
})

update()
```

Nice game btw. I hope you make something cool in the end.

Comment: Now it is working just fine, thanks